# Symfony2 unique constraint already in use

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

my UserTrack entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="JJ\MainBundle\Repository\UserTrackRepository")
 * @ORM\Table
 * @UniqueEntity({"user", "track"})
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class UserTrack implements RateableInterface
...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="JJ\MainBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="user_tracks", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    protected $user;
...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="JJ\MainBundle\Entity\Track", inversedBy="user_tracks")
     * @JMS\Expose
     */
    protected $track;
...
```

When I call:

```
$this->validator->validate($userTrack);
```

This is my exception (when I update my entity):

```
message": "JJ\\MainBundle\\Entity\\UserTrack.user:\n This value is already used.\n",
```

Although I can clearly see that it IS unique:
[image]

Please enlighten me...

Comment: What's the value of `$userTrack`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly it's the UserTrack entity. ID 93 from screenshot. .e.g `die(var_dump($userTrack->getUser()->getId() . ' and ' . $userTrack->getTrack()->getId()));` gives me `'92343396 and 61'`

Comment: Can you show us the update code?